# For comprehension with Future[String] and Future[List[String]]

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

Simplified code:

```
val one: Future[String] = Future("1")
val many: Future[List[String]] = Future({"1","2","3"})

for { 
  a <- one
  b <- many
} yield {
  doSomething(a,b) // Type mismatch, expected String, actual: List[String]
}
```

What I want to happen is to call for each couple of one/many and get a list of the outputs

```
 {doSomething("1","1"),doSomething("1","2"),doSomething("1","3")}
```

Can I get this to work with for comprehensions even when one is a `Future[String]` and the other a `Future[List[String]]`?

Comment: `{"1","2","3"}` is not valid syntax, but I get your point. Do you want a `Future[List[X]]` as the result or a `List[Future[X]]`?

Comment: Then you would need to wait for the futures... which in some sense defeats the purpose of having them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
  val one: Future[String] = Future("1")
  val many: Future[List[String]] = Future(List("1","2","3"))

  def doSomething(a: String, b: String) = ???

  for {
    a <- one
    b <- many
  } yield {
    b.map(v => doSomething(a, v))
  }
```

Alternatively we could use scalaz [`ListT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35707395/5205022) transformer like so

```
  import scalaz._
  import ListT._
  import scalaz.std.scalaFuture.futureInstance

  val one: Future[String] = Future("1")
  val many: Future[List[String]] = Future(List("1","2","3"))

  def doSomething(a: String, b: String) = ???

  for {
    a <- listT(one.map(v => List(v)))
    b <- listT(many)
  } yield {
    doSomething(a, b)
  }
```